# Transpose rows after Join and Groupby in SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, string, group-by, pivot, window-functions

I have some SQL Server tables:

- Employees [EmpID (pk), Name, Designation]
- Projects [PID (pk), EmpID (fk), PCode, PName, Dept]

The tables have a many-to-one relation, that is, one employee can work on multiple projects.

I want to show the result in such a way that each employee has only one row and all the projects he worked on are shown in the column section grouped according to the PCode.

I am unable to understand how to transpose the rows into the column when the number of columns generated are unknown.

Sample Data:

Employee:

```
EmpId  Name  Designation
------------------------
001    Mat   Manager
002    Ash   Developer
003    Paul  Analyst
```

Projects:

```
PID EmpID PCode PName       Dept
-------------------------------------
1   001   111   Project1    Sales
2   001   111   Project1.1  Retail
3   001   222   Project2    Banking
4   002   222   Project2.1  Retail
```

Sample output:

```
EmpID Name Project-1           Project-2              Project-3           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
001   Abc  111,Project1,Sales  111,Project1.1,Retail  222,Project2,Banking
002   Def  222,Project2.1,Retail
```

Comment: provide sample data and your desired output in table format

Comment: Updated the question. Please check

Comment: which version of sql server you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate the projects of each employee in a subquery with `row_number()`, then use conditional aggregation to pivot in the outer query:

```
select e.empid, e.name,
    max(case when rn = 1 then concat_ws(',', p.pcode, p.pname, p.pdept) end) project1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then concat_ws(',', p.pcode, p.pname, p.pdept) end) project2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then concat_ws(',', p.pcode, p.pname, p.pdept) end) project3
from employee e
inner join (
    select p.*, row_number() over(partition by empid order by pid) rn
    from projects p
) p on p.empid = e.empid
group by e.empid, e.name
```

Comment: Its giving me this error "Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by empid order by pid) rn

Comment: @user8306074: that’s a MySQL error message. Why did you tag your question SQL Server? `row_number()` I available in MySQL 8.0 only.

Comment: I have a huge dataset and don't know the maximum projects for each employee. So, in that scenario how can I generate multiple project columns ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PIVOT` command for transpose you data. With your case which you unknown the number of column generated are unknown. You need to query for finding the columns' name of column generated then you can concatenate you all your column's name with `PIVOT` command as below query statement.

```
DECLARE @columnName NVARCHAR(MAX), @pivotSql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT 
    em.EmpID,
    em.Name,
    pr.Pname,
    pr.Pcode + ',' + pr.PName + ',' + pr.Dept Detail
INTO #temp
FROM Employee em 
INNER JOIN Projects pr ON em.EmpID = pr.EmpID 

SELECT 
    t.PName name
INTO #AllProject
FROM #temp t
GROUP BY t.PName

SET @columnName = '';

DECLARE 
    @projectName VARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE cursor_allProject CURSOR
FOR SELECT 
        name
    FROM 
        #AllProject;
OPEN cursor_allProject;
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_allProject INTO @projectName;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @columnName = @columnName + ', [' + @projectName + ']';
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_allProject INTO @projectName;
    END;
CLOSE cursor_allProject;
DEALLOCATE cursor_allProject;


SET @pivotSql = 'SELECT t.EmpID, t.Name FROM #temp t PIVOT t.Detail (FOR t.Pname IN ('+ @columnName +') )'

EXEC (@pivotSql)
```

Comment: which version of SQL are you using ?

Comment: You can use with any SQL Server